How do I convert two character values of a variable to a numerical one?
I have a dataset called "ess".
There is a variable, called ess$trstprl .
Its class is a factor, and it has values "No trust at all",1:9,"Complete trust" .
What I need to do is convert the "No trust at all" and "Complete trust" variables, so that they display "0" and "10" , instead of the text.
All my attempts have failed so far. Any advice would be appreciated! Also if possible, since this is a homework assignment, I need to refrain from using dplyr, so just do it in base R, if possible.
table(ess$trstprl)
class(ess$trstprl)

ess$trstprl_binarni=ess$trstprl
for (i in ess$trstprl) {
  if (ess$trstprl=="No trust at all") {
    ess$trstprl[ess$trstprl,]=0
  }
}


This has failed, as the condition apparently has length >1 .

If you then need a numeric variable do then ess$trstprl <- as.numeric(as.character(ess$trstprl)).

Please use minimal reproducible examples others can run using copy & paste. Show desired output entirely. Use dput() for data & specify all non-base packages with library().

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/69482029/680068

A possible solution using "mapvalues" function from the "plyr" package.
trstprl <- sample(c("No trust at all",1:9,"Complete trust"), 100, T)
trstprl <- factor(trstprl, ordered = F)
ess <- data.frame(cbind(trstprl))
unique(ess$trstprl) # will list "No trust at all" and "Complete trust"
install.packages("plyr")
ess$trstprl <- plyr::mapvalues(ess$trstprl, c("No trust at all", "Complete trust"), c("0","10"))
unique(ess$trstprl) # will NOT list "No trust at all" and "Complete trust"

Additional comment: your for-loop has an error.
Line 3 should be ess[ess$trstprl,]=0, not ess$trstprl[ess$trstprl,]=0

You just need to change the levels of the factor.
For example...
test <- factor(c("No_trust", 1:9, "Complete"))

test
 [1] No_trust 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   Complete
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Complete No_trust

Note that the factor levels are by default in alphabetical order. So the following statement will reset the last two levels to "10" and "0"...
levels(test) <- c(1:9, 10, 0) #the numbers will be coerced to character

test
 [1] 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 0

